# Phonegap android application div bg image

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am very new to android application and I made a simple android application using Phonegap.

I created some pages and linked correctly, Its working fine and I would likes to add page transitions as in many applications.

Please help me how to add those transitions. i.e. When a user clicks in the link and this page will slide left and has to show the upcoming page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can either use any jQuery slide transition or the best way is to use the **MobileJquery Framework**

in which you will have a lot of options to customize. Click here for more details [www.jquerymobile.com](http://www.jquerymobile.com)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$.mobile.changePage('#pageid', {
                    transition : "none",
                    reverse : true,
                    changeHash : true
                });
```

to change page. define desired transition here